# Displacement field not correct?

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, deal.ii, elasticity

Consider the elastic equation $$- \operatorname{div}(C \nabla \mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{f}$$ as presented in [step-8](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_8.html#Intro). Here $\mathbf{u}$ is the displacement vector, let's consider the 2d case.

As you can see in the [setup_system](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_8.html#ElasticProblemsetup_system), they impose homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. Then I'd expect to see that the two plots of $x$ and $y$ displacements have 0 as boundary value. However, this is not happening, and I can't understand why. You can see the x_displacement in the following Paraview screenshot. Notice the $-1.6 e-4$ value at the boundary.

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the negative value is at the boundary and not somewhere in the interior? :-)

Comment: shame on me :-) Is there any way to print the values of the solution at the boundary, like a for loop and then `std::cout`? I would loop over all cells, then over all faces, I identify the ones that are on the boundary, and then I'd like to access the solution vector at the degrees of freedom of that boundary face. How can I get the dofs for a boundary face? @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: Someone has thought of that already and wrote the `DataOutFaces` class :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Wolfgang Bangerth , the value may be at the interior points. However, to visualise that better in paraview, You can use a filter called "plot over line" which plots the data points over a given line, which could come very handy for these kinds of clarifications in future.